# How can i display Array values in a single text box using Angular Js?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm displaying list of values fetched from DB. One of its attributes is array. I handled it using table as below,

```
<tr>
  <td>{{movId}}</td>
  <td>{{movtitle}}</td>
  <td>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="mem in mov.cast>{{mem}}</li>
    </ul>
  </td>
</tr>
```

But i've changed it to display in text box instead of table so that i can edit as below,

```
<input type="text" ng-value="movId">
<input type="text" ng-value="movtitle">
```

I don't know how to display array attribute ("Cast") in text box

How to attain this...Hope it is possible...if not any alter way to handle it??

Comment: You may want to take a look at [ngTagsInput](http://mbenford.github.io/ngTagsInput/).

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos
M not gona type in UI mate...rather i would like to display in UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-model`:

```
<input type="text" ng-value="movie.movTitle" ng-model="movie.movTitle"/>
```

I don't know how your data is structured exactly, but you could do it like this:

```
$scope.movies = [
    {
        movId:1234,
        movTitle:'gone with the wind',
        cast:[
            'bill',
            'ben',
            'bart'
       ]
    }
]
```

HTML:

```
<table ng-repeat="movie in movies">
  <tr>
      <td>
          <input type="text" ng-value="movId" ng-model="movie.movId"/>
      </td>
      <td>
          <input type="text" ng-value="movie.movTitle" ng-model="movie.movTitle"/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td ng-repeat="item in movie.cast">
          <input type="text" ng-value="item" ng-model="item"/>
      </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/oLmdzowk/1/)

Comment: Thnks mate..that resolved the prob.
But the 4 text boxes are listed horizontally if cast has 4 values. I want it to be vertical..i used <br> --not working!?

Comment: @VinoSpartan you're welcome - please accept the answer :) To display the cast vertically, you could use the `ng-repeat` in the table row rather than the table cell. EG: http://jsfiddle.net/x3y9p0s2/1/

Comment: No i can't use it so. Because i've one more <td>'s for all to display what it is...
Ex : <tr>
           <td>Cast Details></td>
           <td><input type="text" ng-value="item" ng-model="item"/></td>
       </tr>

If i replace ng-repeat n place in tr means i'll get tf--> Cast Details as much times as values in UI

Comment: @VinoSpartan I'm not sure what you mean exactly, if you get an example up I can take a look.

Comment: Actually for prob point of view i missed a `td` in my question. Original code is 
`<tr>
     <td>Cast Details</td>
     <td ng-repeat="item in cast"><input type="text" ng-value="item" ng-model="item"/></td>`

So as you suggested, if i replace the `ng-repeat` to my `<tr>` 
then my first `<td>Cast Details</td>` also will display many times as much as `item` value